# repaint() doesn't work - what do I wrong

Tags: java, swing, repaint

Could you tell me why my `repaint()` method doesn't work in my code? Do you know some websites from which I can learn the basic stuff. Thanks in advance.

```
public class OknoGry extends JFrame
{   
public static enum Tryb{NOWA_GRA,LISTA_NAJLEPSZYCH, USTAWIENIA,   MENU}                             
private JButton nowa_gra,wyjscie,ustawienia,lista_najlepszych;  

OknoGry()
{
    zaladujPrzysicki();
}


public void zaladujPrzysicki(){

    JFrame okno_gry = new JFrame ("LUNAR LANDER");
    JPanel panel = (JPanel)okno_gry.getContentPane();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    okno_gry.setBounds(0,0,600,400);
    okno_gry.setVisible(true);
    wyjscie = new JButton("Wyjscie");
    wyjscie.setBounds(150, 200, 300, 50);
    wyjscie.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
               System.exit(0);
          }
       });
    panel.add(wyjscie);
    nowa_gra = new JButton("Nowa Gra");
    nowa_gra.setBounds(150,150,300,50);
    nowa_gra.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
               przyciskNowaGra();
            //   repaint();
          }
       });
    panel.add(nowa_gra);
    ustawienia = new JButton("Ustawienia");
    ustawienia.setBounds(150, 100, 300, 50);
    ustawienia.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
               przyciskUstawienia();
          }
       });
    panel.add(ustawienia);

    lista_najlepszych = new JButton("Lista Najlepszych Wynikow");
    lista_najlepszych.setBounds(150, 50, 300, 50);
    lista_najlepszych.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
               przyciskListaNajlepszych();
          }
       });
    panel.add(lista_najlepszych);
    okno_gry.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {                                    
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    okno_gry.setVisible(true);
    okno_gry.setResizable(false);
//  panel.paintComponents(g);

}
protected void przyciskUstawienia() {
    tryb_gry = tryb_gry.USTAWIENIA;
}
protected void przyciskListaNajlepszych() {

    tryb_gry = tryb_gry.LISTA_NAJLEPSZYCH;
}
protected void przyciskNowaGra() {

    tryb_gry = tryb_gry.NOWA_GRA;
    //System.out.println("uzytkowniku kliknales na przysick nowa gra");
    nowa_gra.setVisible(false);
    wyjscie.setVisible(false);
    ustawienia.setVisible(false);
    lista_najlepszych.setVisible(false);
    //System.out.println(tryb_gry);

    repaint();

}
public void rysujMape(Graphics g){                  
        Dimension dim = getSize();                      
        System.out.println("JESTEM W METODZIE rysujMape");
        System.out.println(punkt_y1*dim.height);
        System.out.println(punkt_x2*dim.width);
        g.drawLine(0, punkt_y1*dim.height/100, punkt_x2*dim.width/100, punkt_y2*dim.height/100);                    
        g.drawLine(punkt_x2*dim.width/100, punkt_y2*dim.height/100, punkt_x3*dim.width/100, punkt_y3*dim.height/100);
        g.drawLine(punkt_x3*dim.width/100,punkt_y3*dim.height/100,punkt_x4*dim.width/100,punkt_y4*dim.height/100);
        g.drawLine(punkt_x4*dim.width/100,punkt_y4*dim.height/100, punkt_x5*dim.width/100,punkt_y5*dim.height/100);


}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)           
{   
  super.paintComponent(g);
    System.out.println("jestem w metodzie paintComponent");
    switch(tryb_gry){
    case NOWA_GRA:{

    rysujMape(g);               
    rakieta.rysujRakiete(g);
    break;
    }
    case USTAWIENIA:{
        break;
    }
    case LISTA_NAJLEPSZYCH:{
        break;
    }
    case MENU:{
        break;
    }
    default:{

        break;
    }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //createAndShowGUI();
            OknoGry gf = new OknoGry();
        }
    });
}}
```

I have no idea why it isn't working, please help.

Comment: What do you want to do? Any errors? What is not working? You should at least show some effort before posting a question here, or your questions get downvoted and you don't get much feedback usually. (I didn't downvote it btw, but I understand those who did)

Answer (score 2):

1. Your class is a `JFrame`, which *has* no `paintComponent` method, so aren't actually overriding any paint functionality.
2. You class is already a `JFrame` but you create another `JFrame` instance in the constructor. Why? Don't. Choose one or the other.
3. `paintComponent` should be overridden in `JPanel`. So make a class that extends JPanel, override the `paintComponent` in that panel, then add that panel to your frame.
4. Make use of the `@Override` annotation, so you know if you're properly overriding a method.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Grapchics g) {}
   ```
5. When you call `repaint()` make sure you call it on the panel and not the frame.
6. For more about painting see [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
7. set your frame visible *after* adding your components.
8. Avoid using null layouts. Learn to use layout managers. See [Laying Components Within a container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)